# UIBezierPath curve from far edges

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

In iOS i'm trying to draw a clipped image. I want the clipping to be from one edge, curved to the farthest opposite edge. The below image illustrates in red, the border of the final image. In this example the curve goes from bottom left to top right.

[image]

Here is the code I currently wrote. My only problem is this method  `bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:` does not curve to the extend i need.

```
- (UIImage *)roundCorneredImage:(UIImage *)image radius:(CGFloat)radius {
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectZero;
    imageRect.size = image.size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageRect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(radius, radius);
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:imageRect byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomRight cornerRadii:size] addClip];

    [image drawInRect:imageRect];

    UIImage* result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return result;
}
```

UPDATE:

Heres the result I'm getting and my updated code. I need some further assistance...

[image]

```
UIBezierPath* bezier = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bezier moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[bezier addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, imageRect.size.height)];

[bezier addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(imageRect.size.width / 2, imageRect.size.height / 2)
                  radius:imageRect.size.height / 2
              startAngle:M_PI / 2
                endAngle:0
               clockwise:NO];

[bezier addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [bezier addClip];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres my solution for anyone else who wanted to see some sample code.

```
- (UIImage *)roundCorneredImage:(UIImage *)image radius:(CGFloat)radius {
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectZero;
    imageRect.size = image.size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageRect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    UIBezierPath* bezier = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [bezier moveToPoint:CGPointMake(imageRect.size.width, 0)];
    [bezier addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [bezier addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, imageRect.size.height)];
    [bezier addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(0, 0) radius:imageRect.size.height startAngle:M_PI / 2 endAngle:0 clockwise:NO];
    [bezier addClip];

    [image drawInRect:imageRect];

    UIImage* result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the straight lines with `addLineToPoint` and the curve with `addArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:` so that you have control over the shape of the curve.

Comment: I'm new to this area of iOS and don't have a full understanding of what all the params will be. Can you update your answer with sample code so I can get it to work and then I'll be able to tweak it from there. Thanks

Comment: @cnotethegr8 that might be a good opportunity to look at [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/addArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:)

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist the documentation wont help me. Its the fine details I need now. I'm not sure how to complete the curve. I'll update my question with my updated code.